# Is there a more efficient way of ensuring my database gets closed?

Tags: ruby

I'm using the Daybreak library, which is a key/value store.

I open it to perform any operation with this:

```
db = Daybreak::DB.new $ShowDatabaseName
```

Then I do whatever I want, and then close it with this:

```
db.close
```

It seems like wasted effort to this everywhere I want to use it however. It seems like it might be more efficient to declare it as a class variable in initialize like this:

```
def initialize

    @db = Daybreak::DB.new $ShowDatabaseName

end
```

It means the rest of my class can use it without initializing and closing it each time, but then I get a message reading:

```
Daybreak database was not closed, state might be inconsistent
```

Is there a better way of doing this, which deals with both the repetition and the warning?

Comment: What are you using Daybreak for? If it is only for storing Key-Value pairs, perhaps a Hash can do the job just as well?  If you are using it to interact with a database, you might consider using sqlite3 instead.

Comment: To store key-value pairs after the program is finished running, which will be there when it opens again.

Answer (score 4):

Use a block:

```
def use_db(database_name)
  db = Daybreak::DB.new(database_name)
  yield db
ensure 
  db.close
end

use_db($ShowDatabaseName) do |db|
  # do something with db
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to (sort of) ensure that the database connection is closed when the program finishes, use an `at_exit` block. So, store your connection as a constant (your variable is an instance variable):

```
DB = Daybreak::DB.new $ShowDatabaseName
```

And somewhere else in your program (anywhere) put an `at_exit` block:

```
at_exit {
  DB.close
}
```

Comment: I stick `at_exit` blocks at the end of the file. It seems more sensible than putting them at the top.